# Is there anyway where I can compare structures of struct made using pointers?

Tags: c, sorting, struct

I'm working on a problem where there is an array of dates to be sorted and in its order the input has to be displayed (sorted one). There are two dates one is sow date and other is harvest date. Based on the input they are to be sorted and displayed.

Initially number of crops input is taken and with that name, rainfall, temp, sow date, harvest date are taken. crops usually are two or more, I've been able to write only comparison for two crops but I need it for more than two. Additionally Case 3 and 4 I'm not able to figure out. Struct `Date` and struct `Crop` are to be kept mandatory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Date {
    int dd;
    int mm;
    int yyyy;
};

struct Crop {
    char name[30];
    float rainfall;
    int temperature;
    struct Date *sowDate;
    struct Date *harvestDate;
} c;

int main(void) {
    printf("Enter the number of Crops\n");
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);

    struct Crop *list = (struct Crop *)malloc(num * sizeof(struct Crop));

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("Enter the details of Crops %d\n", i + 1);
        printf("Enter name\n");
        scanf(" %s", list[i].name);
        printf("Enter rainfall\n");
        scanf("%f", &list[i].rainfall);
        printf("Enter temperature\n");
        scanf("%d", &list[i].temperature);

        list[i].sowDate = (struct Date *)malloc(sizeof(struct Date));
        list[i].harvestDate = (struct Date *)malloc(sizeof(struct Date));
        printf("Enter sowDate\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &list[i].sowDate->dd, &list[i].sowDate->mm, &list[i].sowDate->yyyy);
        printf("Enter harvestDate\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &list[i].harvestDate->dd, &list[i].harvestDate->mm, &list[i].harvestDate->yyyy);
    }

    printf("Menu\n");
    printf("1)Crop that needs the highest rainfall\n");
    printf("2)Crop that needs the highest temperature\n");
    printf("3)Display the crop sorted in ascending order of the sowDate\n");
    printf("4)Display the crop sorted in ascending order of the harvestDate\n");
    printf("Enter your Choice\n");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    switch (j) {
      case 1:
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if (list[i].rainfall > list[i + 1].rainfall)
                printf("Crop that needs the highest rainfall is %s\n", list[i].name);
            else 
                printf("Crop that needs the highest rainfall is %s\n", list[i + 1].name);
            break;
        }
      case 2:
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            if (list[i].temperature > list[i + 1].temperature)
                printf("Crop that needs highest temperature is %s\n", list[i].name);
            else
                printf("Crop that needs highest temperature is %s\n", list[i + 1].name);
            break;
        }
      case 3:
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
            break;
      case 4:
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
            break;
      default:
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program interaction:

```
Enter the number of Crops
2
Enter the details of Crops 1
Enter name
Rice
Enter rainfall
15
Enter temperature
23
Enter sowDate
25 7 2016
Enter harvestDate
30 11 2016
Enter the details of Crops 2
Enter name
Wheat
Enter rainfall
7
Enter temperature
29
Enter sowDate
24 7 2016
Enter harvestDate
31 11 2016
Menu
1)Crop that needs the highest rainfall
2)Crop that needs the highest temperature
3)Display the crop sorted in ascending order of the sowDate
4)Display the crop sorted in ascending order of the harvestDate
Enter your Choice
1
Crop that needs the highest rain fall is Rice
Menu
1)Crop that needs the highest rainfall
2)Crop that needs the highest temperature
3)Display the crop sorted in ascending order of the sowDate
4)Display the crop sorted in ascending order of the harvestDate
Enter your Choice
2
Crop that needs the highest temperature is Wheat
Menu
1)Crop that needs the highest rainfall
2)Crop that needs the highest temperature
3)Display the crop sorted in ascending order of the sowDate
4)Display the crop sorted in ascending order of the harvestDate
Enter your Choice
3   
Wheat
7.00
29
24 7 2016
31 11 2016
Rice
15.00
23
25 7 2016
30 11 2016
Menu
1)Crop that needs the highest rainfall
2)Crop that needs the highest temperature
3)Display the crop sorted in ascending order of the sowDate
4)Display the crop sorted in ascending order of the harvestDate
Enter your Choice
4
Rice
15.00
23
25 7 2016
30 11 2016
Wheat
7.00
29
24 7 2016
31 11 2016
Menu
1)Crop that needs the highest rainfall
2)Crop that needs the highest temperature
3)Display the crop sorted in ascending order of the sowDate
4)Display the crop sorted in ascending order of the harvestDate
Enter your Choice
5
EXIT
```

Comment: 1) Compare the year-parts; if they are different, the dates are different. 2) compare the months,idem. 3) compare the days,idem.4) they are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is homework so I will not give complete solutions, but I'll give "points to consider".

```
        case 1 :
          for(i=0;i<num;i++)
          {
              if(list[i].rainfall>list[i+1].rainfall)  // (1)
                  printf("Crop that needs the highest rainfall is %s\n",list[i].name);
              else 
                  printf("Crop that needs the highest rainfall is %s\n",list[i+1].name);
              break; // (2)
          }  // (3)
```

(1): are you sure that if this is true, yuo have found the highest?

(2): are you sure you now want to break the `for` loop?

(3): this is the end of the `case 1:`. What will be the next statement that will be executed?

Note: what will be the max value of `i+1`? Does that element exist?

---

The same remarks for `case 2:`

---

`case 3:` *Display the crop sorted in ascending order of the sowDate*

This means you must sort `list`. Aside, the name should better be something like `cropArray` because it is not a list.

Lookup "man quicksort". It gives you a sort function available in many C libraries. You must write a compare function that compares two sow dates.

---

`case 4:` well, that will be easy now. Just write another compare function for quicksort.